# Load More option without databse query using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can set load more option without database query using jQuery bu class name.

Comment: Is this a solution or question?

Comment: why did you push the ask question button??

Comment: There is neither a problem statement nor a question here. Please review [ask]

Comment: This question and also I have mentioned answer which is work fine for me..As well as need to know more suggestion or solution for this question

Comment: Why are you trying to ask and answer your own questions? That isn't the purpose of stack overflow, stack overflow is for getting help with problems you're having. If you had a problem and found a solution then great, but don't ask poorly worded questions and then answer them yourself, it doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got solution for this question.

```
jQuery(".qs").hide();

jQuery(".qs").slice(0, 15).show();

var getshowingcount = jQuery(".qs:visible").length;

if(getshowingcount >=15){   
     jQuery(document).delegate(".view_more_link_bottom","click",function(e){

    var showing = jQuery(".qs:visible").length;

    jQuery(".qs").slice(showing - 1, showing + 15).show();

    });
}else{
    jQuery(".view_more_link_bottom").hide();    
}
```